# PHP MYSQL JOIN display

Tags: php, mysql

I have multiple tables in MYSQL, both have Customer_ref and Customer_name fields, I'm trying to fix an issue where some of the Customer names are different in one of the tables. I've written a join to display information from both tables is it possible to display both Customer_names within the join? For example:

```
while($row_join = mysqli_fetch_array($result_sqlUpdateCust_v_lists)) {
    echo $row_join['compliance_customers.Customer_name']
        . " | "
        . $row_join['cust_v_lists.Customer_name']
        . "<br>";
}
```

Maybe it's not possible, but would just make things faster if I could. I'll probably have to load one set into an array and compare the array to the other table.

Comment: `Join` on customer_ref. Use Aliasing and fetch the name columns from different tables.

Comment: I had never used Aliasing before in sql, that is fantastic, working now, thanks so much. @MadhurBhaiya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by Aliasing as per excellent comment from @madhurbhaiya:

```
SELECT compliance_customers.Customer_name, 
    compliance_customers.Customer_ref,
    cust_v_lists.Customer_name AS listsName
FROM cust_v_lists 
INNER JOIN compliance_customers ON compliance_customers.Customer_ref = cust_v_lists.Customer_ref
WHERE Live = 'Yes'
```